# How to use hslogger to pring log with timestamp and priority and send info log to stdout?

Tags: haskell, logging, hslogger

I'm using `hslogger` and had the following code working to print info log to stdout, but it doesn't show the timestamp and priority

```
import System.Log.Logger
  ( Priority(..)
  , infoM
  , errorM
  , rootLoggerName
  , setLevel
  , updateGlobalLogger
  )

main :: IO ()
main = do
  updateGlobalLogger rootLoggerName (setLevel INFO)
  infoM "main" "starting"
  errorM "main" "something wrong"
```

The log is like

```
starting
something wrong
```

But I'd like the log to be something like:

```
[2018-05-12 10:00:00.000Z] [INFO] starting
[2018-05-12 10:00:00.000Z] [ERROR] something wrong
```

How can I make change to do it? 
Thanks

Comment: Is there an issue with making `myInfoM` and `myErrorM` that can use `getCurrentTime` and prepend the desired string?

Comment: Good idea. Thanks!